# Geth returns tx hash but blockchain

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, etherscan, hash, sendtransaction

I have a Geth server on light mode, and implemented sending transactions based on [web3.php](https://github.com/sc0Vu/web3.php) project. Everything works well, except sending transactions.
The code I am using sends `from`, `to`, and `value` and other options like `nonce`, `gas`, and `gasPrice` left as their defaults and are not set. Transaction happens and I receive the TX hash, but when I explore it, there is not anything about it on the Ethereum blockchain.
This is an example:

https://etherscan.io/tx/0x46d52b2d8dea9cf2a98095324905bef8db7cd6556776d1d8a04c53a9a39c59b0

And this is the output in etherscan:

[image]
On the other hand, nothing happened on the sender address whereas I have received TX hash!

I'm sure that the sender address has enough fund to send and provide gas price.  I'm really confused and cannot know what is the problem.

Comment: Your node is probably not fully synced.

Comment: @goodvibration, `eth.syncing` is `false`

Comment: And after some hour, a strange behavior on Ethereum blockchain happened. The transaction which was unknown and there was not on the network, is succeed right now! I don't know how can I handle such behaviors on Ethereum blockchain

Comment: Your node was **definitely** not fully synced.

Comment: @goodvibration, how can I detect if my light node is fully synced?

Comment: Check its current block number and compare to the latest block number by querying a fully-synced node. I have a script for that, which checks the latest block number on Etherscan, but it's written in Javascript (where your code-base is in PHP according to your question). You don't have to use Etherscan of course, it can be any other public node, as long as it is properly synced.

Comment: I've checked both, and the current block number were same as each other. Can this happen because I am using a light node?

Comment: I would guess so. The node still has to sync at least some of the current state in order for the block (in which your transaction is included) to be properly synced with the blockchain that it is about to be added to.